# Accessing intra-window widget hierarchy

Tags: x11

[Editres](http://www.rahul.net/kenton/editres.html) is a pretty powerful program for displaying and even modifying properties of widgets within an application window. I believe it interfaces with the X resources. However, very few programs actually understand its protocol (for instance, Firefox does not). Is there a similar program or perhaps a command line tool for displaying widget hierarchy in any given window? A program like `xprop` will work on any window in the X Window System, but it (as far as I know) only retrieves information about an entire window and not the widget tree within it.

For context, I am working with the GNOME desktop environment on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many modern widget toolkits don't use X windows for each widget, but instead manage the widgets manually as part of the library. As such, there's no protocol to intercept like you can with traditional X programs. These toolkits do expose widget tree information in other ways, though. GTK 2 had https://live.gnome.org/Accerciser, which appears to work with GTK 3.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestion. Unfortunately, I have not been able to properly install it, but the screenshots indicate this is what I am looking for.

Comment: @user50138: you probably need to install a bunch of devel packages to build and install it. Post the error messages and maybe I can point you in the right direction (or ask a new question on SuperUser...).